# clang-format pointer syntax alignment with multiple declarations on one line

Tags: c++, clang-format

With a C++ input file such as:

```cpp
int *p1;
int *p2, *p3;
```

I can run `clang-format` using the Chromium style; which has a `Left` value for the `PointerAlignment` option. But when I do, only `p1` has its pointer star aligned to the left:

`$ clang-format -style=chromium what.cpp`

```cpp
int* p1;
int *p2, *p3;
```

Is there another option which can affect the pointer star alignment when multiple variables are declared in the same statement?

Comment: What would you expect it to look like? Can you add an example?

Comment: Never declare multiple variables in one statement like that, it's bad practice. Always declare your variables immediately before you use them.

Comment: Worth clarifying between clang-tidy and clang-format. Looks like it is clang-format that you're discussing. And, I mean, for `p3`, where else can the `*` possibly go? You wrote *yourself* into that corner.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, I meant `clang-format` - I've updated, thanks. The `p3` star could go beside the comma; but even if `p3` was not a pointer, the star at `p2` will still remain on the right. @Galik Multiple variables in such a statement may well be about to be used. Of course, in real code, all variables should be initialised.

Comment: Do you which to change it to `int* p2,* p3;`? looks scary.

Comment: A pointer to a comma? clang-format was right not to touch the `*` on that line.

Comment: @MarekR I don't want to change it to that. I'm asking if `clang-format` has the option to format pointers declared in such statements.